# Trying to install maya plugin wizard, but no folder vcprojects in Visual Studio, what to do?

Tags: visual-studio, maya

Sorry, I am a newbie and it's my first time working with Visual Studio.
I am trying to install Maya plugin wizard. In readme.txt file for Maya plugin wizard says :

**Copy the following files to the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\vcprojects" folder**

But I don't have such a path. If I open *C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio*, I have 3 folders - *"2019", "Installer", "Shared"*. I tried to go with this path C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC, but there is no folder called "vcprojects", there are only 3 folders again - "Auxiliary", "Redist", "Tools".

I also tried to look in Visual Studio folder for "VCWizards" folder since it's also required for installation as readMe.txt told me and found it here - C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\VC, but there was no "vcprojects" folder again.

Can anybody tell me what should I do, where to look or maybe should I make a path manually?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by creating the `VCProjects` folder in:
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\VC`

You will also need to update the `Wizard=VsWizard.VsWizardEngine.14.0` variable to `Wizard=VsWizard.VsWizardEngine.16.0` in `MayaPluginWizard.vsz`